# Templates for generating timesheets

Tags: templates, calculations, calendar

Are there templates for generating weekly time sheets in LaTeX?  Ideally something that would minimize duplicate entries by computing totals and days-of-week.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](http://micha.elmueller.net/tag/timesheet-template/) link. IMHO TeX is not the best solution for such a task. I personally would write some kind a script for generating data in one of my favorite scripting languages (shell+AWK or Python) and then just dump the data into his templates.

Comment: Very nice templates.

Answer (score 1):

For my hourly/weekly timesheets, I use a BASH script that minimizes duplicates entries by computing totals. All hours are stored in a plaintext file and the script reads from it and inserts it into a LaTeX document.

See [GitHub](https://github.com/bamos/simple-shell-scripts/tree/master/timesheets) for the raw files and [my blog](http://bamos.github.com/2013/02/10/timesheets-with-bash-and-latex/) for annotations and a short writeup.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)